# mongoose findOneandUpdate running twice inside findOne

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async.js

I am using `async eachSeries` and updating the document when it is present. Here is the sample code.

```
let a = [ 
 { user_name: "foo" } 
];
async.eachSeries(a, (doc, done) => {

    Foo.findOne(doc).lean(true).exec((err, doc) => {

        if (err) return done(err);
        Foo.findOneAndUpdate(a, {
                user_last: "bar"
            }, {
                upsert: true,
                new: true
            },
            (err, doc) => {
                if (err) return done(err);
                return done(doc);
            });
    });
}, (err) => {
    console.log(completed);
});
```

sometime even the array `a` has one element , the `findOneAndUpdate` function is running twice in a single  iteration. I am using `node v6.10` and `mongoose`. It not happening all the time.

Is any one has encountered the similar problem.

Comment: There's more than just a couple of things that don't really make sense here. Of course this is just an "exercise" but if you really have code that is structured like this, then you really need to change it. There should be no logical reason to `.findOne()` and then `findOneAndUpdate()`. At best you want to "loop" some things and update based on the values present in the current documents. But if that is what you are "really" trying to do, then code based on this structure is just the wrong approach. You'd do better to instead show what you really need to do.

Comment: Also just noticed here that you are using `a` which is the "array" inside the `eachSeries()` rather than `doc` which is actually the "each" element. Unclear again whether you have the same production code mistake or not because this clearly is not your production code.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code like

```
let arr = [ 
    { user_name: "foo" } 
];

async.eachSeries(arr, (query, done) => {
    // note the removal of lean() as we want a document to use .save()
    Foo.findOne(query).exec((err, doc) => {
        if (err) 
            return done(err);
        // if no document is found, judging by your code you want to create a new document
        if (!doc) {
            doc = new Foo();
        }
        // at this point you will have an existing or new document
        doc.user_last = "bar";
        doc.save(done);
    });
}, (err) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('completed');
});
```